# Inspecting windows app elements with Appium Desktop - not all window elements detected

Tags: appium

## Description

I am running an Appium Desktop server to inspect and test windows applications. I am trying to run a first test which simply opens the Windows Notepad and inspects all its window elements. The desired capabilities are as represented by the following JSON:

```
{
    "platformName": "Windows",
    "deviceName": "WindowsPC",
    "app": "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
}
```

## Problems faced

Under the "Select Elements" option, the opened Notepad Window has only some of its elements detected. It appears to be only the scroll bar and its buttons. None of the menu items are detected, for example.

The following message appears:

"Using the Webview inspector in Appium Desktop is less accurate in retrieving and selecting DOM elements in comparison to using the DevTools of Chrome and Safari."

This is shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

I have done this to try and reproduce what is shown in several tutorials, and in those, all the elements are detected, and no such message as above appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the correct driver.

You may want to take a look at the Windows Desired Capabilities page.
https://github.com/appium/appium-windows-driver#windowsdriver-specific-capabilities

I haven't used the built in inspector to much but Visual Studio has a great inspection tool built into for windows applications.

Hope this helps.